# CSS Blury background Effect

Tags: css, image, background, blur, effect

How can I make the background image blury (or what it is in the picture) as the bakground in the picture?
I mean, it's not just a simple blurring, it seems to have used several filters

I tried blur Effect but it's not the same!

[Picture with blured background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouYZa.jpg)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and describe in what way it is failing.

Comment: Hi! I think the effect you're looking for is called "acrylic" or "frosted glass". There is also either some fog in the background image or a semi-transparent light grey gradient overlay — it gives its own touch, too.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question seems incomplete, here is a solution.
This below line blurs everything behind the element it's applied to

```
backdrop-filter: blur(5px);
```